# Get logs of .exe file in java

Tags: java, launch4j

I have tried converting .jar to .exe using launch4j first time.

Able to execute .jar perfectly fine. But converted exe is not working properly, there seems to be something error.

Is there a way that I can get logs for .exe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the `.exe` file from the command line so that the error shows up in the console.